No internet in systemd-nspawn
Tried No internet connection in chroot environment solution without  succeess (copying resolv.conf)
machinectl login helloworld
uname -a
Linux cas12-Yoga-7-14ITL5 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ping 8.8.8.8:
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

